# How to do the counting when computing the fault tolerant threshold of quantum codes?

Tags: error-correction, experimental-realization, fault-tolerance, topological-quantum-computing

Here, I want to ask a basic question about how to compute the fault tolerance threshold of quantum codes. As I know, maybe, the most usual way is to do some simulations. Howvever, I am more intersted with the theoretical computation. More specificly, I am interested with the quantum LDPC relted codes, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6172, https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08351, and https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2984. For example, let us talk about

Efficient decoding of random errors for quantum expander codes, by Fawzi,Grospellier,and Leverrier, STOC’18.

My first question is about the failure probability $\epsilon$ (or success probability $1-\epsilon$ in verse). I am confused by the computation of that. Do we need to count **all** the random errors that can not be corrected succesfully? In that paper, the authors can correct random errors of linear weight with a very high probability $1-\epsilon$. Denote by $\delta n$ the weight of the random errors, where $0<\delta\leq1$ and $n$ is the block length. In general, we can assume that $0<\delta<0.5$ (Is it right or necessary?). Then do we need to deal with the random errors of weight larger than $\delta n$ up to $n$?